# Jquery onmouseover not working

Tags: jquery, attr, onmouseover

When I move my mouse over any one of the DIVs with a class of `.notif`, I want the `background` colour and `border-left` styles to be removed completely but it's not working within my code - I don't see either the `alert` or the `console.log` message.
I will have several divs with the same class - only the one that is hovered over should have the background removed.

I **don't want** to `toggle` or `hover`, as I'm **not looking to change the colour back** when the user moves their mouse away again. The background colour should be left as white.

It's works in JS fiddle using `.addClass()` or `.attr()` to set the background back to white but the script doesn't work elsewhere. I've got other JS/Jquery scripts in place that work so it's not that I've forgotten to include the URLs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".notif").mouseover(function() {
    //console.log('mouseover detected!!');
    //alert('Mouse!');
    $(this).addClass("notif_read");
    //$(this).attr("style","background-color:white");
  });
});
```

```css
.notif {
  background: aliceblue;
  border-left: darkblue;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
.notif_read {
  background: white;
  border-left: none;
  border-left-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="notifications container" style="width: 400px; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <h6 style="margin-left:40px;"><div class="notification-heading">Unread Notifications</div></h6>
  <hr class="notification-divider">
  <div class="notif row">
    <a href="?function=show&amp;id=47930">
      <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
        <img src="https://wb-dev.workbooks.com/resources/3AjMwETM/wb_icon_small.png" height="70px" width="70px">
        <input class="case_ref" type="hidden" value="CASE-32109">#
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center text-muted">Workbooks Support updated CASE-32109</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="notif row">
    <a href="?function=show&amp;id=47930">
      <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
        <img src="https://wb-dev.workbooks.com/resources/3AjMwETM/wb_icon_small.png" height="70px" width="70px">
        <input class="case_ref" type="hidden" value="CASE-32109">#
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center text-muted">Workbooks Support updated CASE-32109</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  </hr>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ha4pwd4o/3/

Comment: The code works fine in your included snippet as well. When you run the code in the environment where it's "not working", are there any console errors?

Comment: No errors... I don't see the console.log or alert message in my code either. I will update the Question with HTML that I actually output.. this is just a simplified version

Comment: I tested your code and did not see any problem. background changes and alert works and console logs.

Comment: Hmm... I'm so confused then! What could the possible reasons for this not firing correctly in my environment? Even though other scripts work perfectly fine...

Comment: This is probably not gonna fix it, but your last `</hr>` should be `<hr>` (now it could be mistaken for the closing tag of the first `<hr>`). *Better yet, change them both to: `<hr />`, that's how all self-closing tags should really be written (including `<img />`, `<input />` and `<br />`).*

Comment: I copied the output from Google Chrome console... it should be one single HR tag before the divs for each notification, hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: @myfunkyside I'm open to all suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally resolved this query! Although the example above works as intended. Within my environment, the code sides within a dropdown menu. It is dynamically created by AJAX (every 10 minutes, I check a database for new notifications, generate HTML on the fly append it to the existing list) - I think maybe the DOM doesn't know about the new DIVs, therefore cannot change them onmouseover.

Final code which I hope helps someone:

```
    $("#notification_menu").on("mouseover", ".notif", function() {
        console.log('mouseover detected!!');
        $(this).addClass('notif_read');
    });
```